# Upload Media files to Folder Extend in Umbraco

Tags: file-upload, umbraco, umbraco7

I develop a Umbraco website, i want to move Media folder to a another place in IIS and change upload function to upload files to this Folder, and URL auto general by Umbraco is redirect to this Media folder.

I had research and i see Umbraco just support upload Media files to Azure or Amazon, but don't see for a server.

Thank everyone.

Comment: Why would you want to move your files to another location on the same server? This is an old post, but try it: http://www.proworks.com/blog/archive/how-to-redirect-the-umbraco-media-path-to-another-location/

Comment: I think the interface Umbraco uses for saving files is called `IFileSystemProvider` take a look at how this project does it https://github.com/ElijahGlover/Umbraco-S3-Provider

Comment: Thank everyone, it help me so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload there media files to another place in the same instance of IIS, for example a different folder, there are several things you can do.

1) map your other location to the /media folder on your site as a virtual folder in IIS. That will just work out of the box, and all of your existing media files will continue to work if you move them to the location you're mapping to.

2) change the path in the file /config/FileSystemProviders.config, look for the virtualRoot parameter. By default, it's set to "~/media/", but you can change it.

Hope that helps!